# How to implement oAuth 2.0 in Tizen

Tags: javascript, jquery, oauth-2.0, tizen, tizen-web-app

I'm trying to implement google authentication using oAuth 2.0 in Tizen. I'm following the step from [here](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ForDevices). Based on the instructions from the link, I can able to obtain the user code. but i'm always getting invalid request for obtaining the access and refresh token. My request is as follows.

```
var urlToken ="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token?"+ 
        encodeURI("client_id=<<my client id>>&" +
        "client_secret=<<my client secret>>&" + 
        "code=<<Device code received in first step>>&" +
        "grant_type=authorization_code");
$.ajax({
    url:urlToken,
    type:"POST",        
    headers:{
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "Content-length" : "250"
    },
    accepts: "applicatin/json",
    success:function(response){
        console.log("access token response success");
        console.log(response.access_token)
    },
    error:failure
});
```

I couldn't able to figure out what goes wrong. Please update it there is any other way to implement the same.

**Note:** I'm trying to implement this from the Tizen Webapp.

Comment: Why are you setting `"Content-length" : "250"` header by hand? What do you mean by "I'm always getting invalid request" - does google returns this information? Or does the request fail on some transportation layer before it is even send?

Comment: Content-length is one of the option i got in other questionnaire. Removing that also gives me the same result. invalid request is the return response i can able to see using rest client of firefox. It is giving 400 Bad request. Yes i'm receiving the response from google. A

Comment: Have you tried to make it work outside of Tizen? I'm not familiar with that library so I'm not sure if and how i may affect your requests.

Comment: Yeah. I tried to do it by simple ajax request using restclient (Firefox add-on).

Comment: And...? Result was the same "invalid request"?

Comment: yes. it is giving the same response.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26458/discussion-between-wtk-and-brune)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got things working with the following code. I made a mistake by marking the data in query string as well as setting content-type and content-length explicitly. Content-type is the by default "application/x-www-form-urlencode". Got the solution by random click.

```
var urlToken ="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"+ 
var dataValue = "client_id=<<my client id>>&" +
        "client_secret=<<my client secret>>&" + 
        "code=<<Device code received in first step>>&" +
        "grant_type=http://oauth.net/grant_type/device/1.0";
$.ajax({
    url:urlToken,
    data:dataValue,
    crossDomain:true,
    type:"POST",
    success:function(response){
      if(response.error != null){
            <<Call the same function again>>;
        }
        else{
            console.log("Access Token :" + response.access_token);
            console.log("Token Type : " + response.token_type);
            console.log("Expires : " + response.expires_in);
            console.log("Refresh Token : " + response.refresh_token);
        }
    },
    error:failure
});
```

Thanks [WTK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/909376/wtk)

I believe [this](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication) and [this](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ForDevices) will be helpful

Comment: Hi @Brune, I'm trying to develop tizen web application with google login, can you please help me with this.

Comment: @venky Sure.. But I've touched google auth & tizen for sometime now. I'm not sure whether the info i provide will help you.. If I'm correct the version i used in tizen is obsolete now.. but yeah, shoot your query.. I'll try..